# Live-action/CGI battlemech movie from before 2005

Tags: story-identification, movie

The plot involved three pilots, I believe a white guy, white girl, and black guy, belonging to the same team/force being deployed to an area and being unable to leave because their mechs are damaged. A local woman has a valuable artifact that looks like a circuit board with a large hemispherical pearl on it. She ends up selling it in order to buy the team weapons for their mechs they use to win and escape. The mechs are mechwarrior-style cockpits on legs, not humanoid. The people are live-action and the mech combat is 90s-style CGI. One of the weapons is a solid red laser beam. The title might have started with an A.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you see this?  (TV, video, theatre...)  What country?  Was it dubbed or subtitled?

Answer (score 3):

Might you be thinking of ***[Gunhed](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097410/?ref_=kw_li_tt)*** (1989)...?

[image: Movie poster for "Gunhed" (1989).]

> In a cyberpunk future, Kyron-5 supercomputer attempts to exterminate the human race, but Gunhed mechs stop it. In 2038, five thieves break into a condemned island facility to steal Kyron's dead CPU. The place turns out to be a deathtrap.

According to the synopsis, five people venture onto an island to steal a CPU, but the three most prominently positioned on the movie poster -- along with a large mech -- are an Asian man, a white woman, and a black man.

Comment: Interesting but I'm afraid not. The CGI was very distinct.

Comment: @Remnant - You said the film was from before 2005, so does that mean you watched it in 2005, or are you just guessing that it's older than that? Also, did you watch this on TV? Video? In a movie theatre?

Comment: On television. Not in a specific year but the house I watched it at was sold in 2005. Most likely between 1998-2002.

Comment: @Remnant - Okay, that rules out the _Pacific Rim_ films, at least. Did the three main characters each pilot their own separate mechs?

Comment: Yes they did. The CGI was definitely 90s style, very reminiscent of Starship Trooper Chronicles.

Comment: @Remnant - _Elysium_ (2003) has animation like that, and features a black man, a white man and a white woman on the poster, along with a boy. But it's full CGI. No live-action.